# django project daesn't work on subdomain

Tags: django, python-2.7, subdomain

I'm new in python and django.

I have virtual hosting account on bluehost.com. I have main site in public_html folder (cms - wordpress). Now I want make django project on subdomain. I found hoster's instruction and setup python 2.7 on my hosting. I installed django 1.6 too (by official manual). Both works correctly (I checked it by ssh-consol)
With django-admin.py I've created app. Also I've created subdomain and directed it to the same folder.

Now I have structure:

```
/user - my account folder<br>
/user/python - python folder<br>
/user/django - django folder<br>
/user/public_html - main site folder<br>
/user/public_html/dev - project and subdomain folder
```

I'm in stalemate, because project doesn't work. When I go on dev.main_site.org, I see just hoster's html default page. But, if I right understood instruction I should see demo project (sign-in page). How to correct it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many steps to be gone through, to host your app. You have to setup an app server, like gunicorn, and connect it to the main server, say apache.. 
May be [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps) should help...

Comment: Yes, I have seen many instruction for VPS. But I hav'nt VPS. I have "shared hosting".